# Why is mawk's output (STDOUT) buffered even though it is the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, buffer, stdout

I am aware that `STDOUT` is usually buffered by commands like `mawk` (but not `gawk`), `grep`, `sed`, and so on, unless used with the appropriate options (i.e. `mawk --Winteractive`, or `grep --line-buffered`, or `sed --unbuffered`). But the buffering doesn't happen when `STDOUT` is a terminal/tty, in which case it is line buffered.

Now, what I don't get is why `STDOUT` is buffered outside of a loop send to a pipe, even though the final destination is the terminal.

A basic example :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | mawk '{print $NF}'
^C
```

Nothing happens for a long time, because `mawk` seems to be buffering it's output.

I wasn't expecting that. **`mawk`'s output is the terminal, so why is its `STDOUT` buffered ?**

Indeed, with the `-Winteractive` option the output is rendering every 3 seconds :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | mawk -Winteractive '{print $NF}'
10:57:05
10:57:08
10:57:11
^C
```

Now, this behavior is clearly `mawk` related, because it isn't reproduced if I use for example `grep`. Even without its `--line-buffered` option, `grep` doesn't buffer its `STDOUT`, which is the expected behavior given that `grep`'s `STDOUT` is the terminal :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | grep Current
Current Time is 11:01:44
Current Time is 11:01:47
Current Time is 11:01:50
^C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655796/why-is-mawks-output-stdout-buffered-even-though-it-is-the-terminal#answer-655807

mawk is buffering its INPUT, which confused me (see also https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/41#issuecomment-241070898)

Carefully reading `mawk`'s manpages gives the answer too :
`-W interactive sets unbuffered writes to stdout and line buffered reads from stdin.`